# Cross Validated does not show up in the Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

Why does Cross Validated not show up in the Data Explorer?

Cr only gives the following sites. Cross gives nothing.

[image]

Comment: An artifact of naming. Try Stat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its name is "Statistical Analysis".
[image]