# Name of SE website names in SEDE don't always match actual SE website names

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer, site-name

I see that the name of SE website names in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag) don't always match actual SE website names. Example:

[image]

while the actual SE website name is Cross Validated. Is that intended?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274641/cross-validated-does-not-show-up-in-the-data-explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, think I found the source of that weird behavior.

Data Explorer is using kind of data dump as its data source, which is a copy of the production database, with security changes and private information removed. This dump is updated once a week.

Now, the public data dump got a file called [Sites.xml](https://ia800500.us.archive.org/22/items/stackexchange/Sites.xml). which contains the name of all sites, along with lots of other useful details about each site.

As you can see, this is the raw XML code for Cross Validated:

```xml
<row Id="10"
    TinyName="stats"
    Name="Stats"
    LongName="Statistical Analysis"
    Url="http://stats.stackexchange.com"
    ImageUrl="//sstatic.net/stats/img/logo.png"
```

As you can see, the name is "Statistical Analysis" and not "Cross Validated". I can't know the reason for that, but looks like SEDE is pulling the names from that same source, hence the confusion.